Sample Variance of the regression coefficient - why does it reduce for more dispersed data?
Thinking on this and I can't see an intuitive reason for this. Given
$$
Var(\hat{\beta}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{S_{xx}}
$$
where
$$
S_{xx} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2
$$
Intuitively, if we have data that is less dispersed shouldn't this mean that the variance within the data is smaller?

You can answer this yourself by considering the limiting case where $S_{xx}=0.$

In this case $x_i = \bar{x}$ and $\sigma^2$ tends to $\infty$ but it doesn't make sense to me why this is (beyond the obvious math). If we have some independent variable such as student's height and we want to predict their weight, why does more variation around the student's heights result in a smaller variance of $\beta$?

Invert the question, please: when $x$ doesn't vary at all, how can you determine any kind of regression line??

Makes sense in that respect - where $x_i = \bar{x}$ then we have no $\beta$. Thank you.
